# How to clean this csv data so that I can read it into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, csv, data-cleaning

I have a CSV files with 20 million rows that looks like this:

```
["{'ev': 'T', 'sym': 'USB', 'i': '52983542396744', 'x': 10, 'p': 48.51, 's': 12, 'c': [14, 37, 41], 't': 1611074854896, 'z': 1}"]

["{'ev': 'T', 'sym': 'CBSH', 'i': '72', 'x': 7, 'p': 70.69, 's': 5, 'c': [37], 't': 1611074854897, 'z': 3}"]

["{'ev': 'T', 'sym': 'ACGL', 'i': '3119', 'x': 12, 'p': 34.32, 's': 100, 't': 1611074854899, 'z': 3}", "{'ev': 'T', 'sym': 'ACGL', 'i': '3120', 'x': 12, 'p': 34.32, 's': 100, 't': 1611074854899, 'z': 3}"]
[]
["{'ev': 'T', 'sym': 'USB', 'i': '53070048741687', 'x': 21, 'p': 48.51, 's': 88, 'c': [14, 37, 41], 't': 1611074854896, 'z': 1}"]
[]
["{'ev': 'T', 'sym': 'ROOT', 'i': '486', 'x': 11, 'p': 19.53, 's': 100, 'c': [14, 41], 't': 1611074854903, 'z': 3}"]
```

The data isn't clean as you can see some rows are empty lists, some dictionaries contain the key "c" while others do not, some lists only have one element while others have more.

I am not sure how to go about cleaning this data.

What I want to ultimately want to do is clean this csv file and then use

```
import pandas as pd
cereal_df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
```

Comment: that doesn't look like a csv... It looks like some weird json

Answer (score 0):

Your data is possibly rows containing lists of Python data structures, as such one approach could be to use the `ast` library to parse each row and convert the text back into actual Python data. This can then be written back out in JSON format.

The Pandas `read_json()` function could be used to read that in. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import ast


json_data = []

with open('file.csv', encoding='utf-8') as f_input:
    for line in f_input:
        line = line.strip()
        
        if line:    # skip any empty lines
            block = ast.literal_eval(line)
           
            for data in block:
                values = ast.literal_eval(data)
                json_data.append(values)
                
with open('output.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f_output:
    json.dump(json_data, f_output)

# Read the JSON file back in using Pandas
df = pd.read_json('output.json')

print(df)
```

This would give you a dataframe as follows:

```
              c ev               i      p    s   sym              t   x  z
0  [14, 37, 41]  T  52983542396744  48.51   12   USB  1611074854896  10  1
1          [37]  T              72  70.69    5  CBSH  1611074854897   7  3
2           NaN  T            3119  34.32  100  ACGL  1611074854899  12  3
3           NaN  T            3120  34.32  100  ACGL  1611074854899  12  3
4  [14, 37, 41]  T  53070048741687  48.51   88   USB  1611074854896  21  1
5      [14, 41]  T             486  19.53  100  ROOT  1611074854903  11  3
```